# Figure out what non-symlink path would be?

Tags: linux, shell, symbolic-link

On Linux, if I've cd'd around and am now in a directory, is there a way to figure out what the real path to that directory is if I had not used a symbolic link to get there?

Consider:

```
$ pwd
/home/dave/tmp
$ mkdir -p 1/2/3/4/5
$ ln -s 1/2/3/4/5 5
$ cd 5
$ pwd 
/home/dave/tmp/5
```

Or:

```
$ pwd
/home/dave/tmp
$ mkdir -p 1/2/3/4/5
$ ln -s 1/2/3/4 4
$ cd 4/5
$ pwd 
/home/dave/tmp/4/5
```

Is there any way to figure out that /home/dave/tmp/5 is really /home/dave/1/2/3/4/5 ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For use with `cd`, use `pwd -P`:

```
$ pwd
/home/dave/tmp
$ mkdir -p 1/2/3/4/5
$ ln -s 1/2/3/4/5 5
$ cd 5
$ pwd 
/home/dave/tmp/5
$ pwd -P
/home/dave/tmp/1/2/3/4/5
```

For generic symbolic links, use `readlink`:

```
$ cd ..
$ readlink 5
1/2/3/4/5
```

Or `ls -l` (with `-d` for directories):

```
$ ls -ld 5
lrwxr-xr-x  1 dave  staff  9 Jul 24 10:10 5 -> 1/2/3/4/5
```

Comment: readlink -f file returns the non-symlinked path to that file, which is what I want.  Thanks!

Comment: huh, I'd always used /bin/pwd, since it can't know how it got where it is, unlike the pwd shell builtin.  Obviously equivalent to pwd -P.

Comment: ls -lda doesn't work for hidden sym links for some reason

Answer (score 2):

You want either `readlink -f` (in coreutils, installed by default) or the more easily-remembered `realpath`, which you have to install.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method I used,

```
cd to the symlink
Ctrl+Shift+T #To open a new tab
pwd
```

New tab pwd, gives the symlink. ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, what shell, window manager, or terminal are you using here?

Comment: I think he's talking about gnome-terminal

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the Gnome Terminal.